# Open a bitmap using default photo viewer without saving file

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap

I have a WinForms app that takes a screenshot, and I want to be able to view this screenshot. Originally I was creating a new instance of a PreviewForm which contained nothing but a picturebox, but if the image being previewed was large, the screenshot is kind of useless.

I'm aware of defining a filepath and using Process.Start(), but this would require this screenshot being saved locally before opening.

Is there no equivalent method to open an image in image viewer from just a bitmap object?

Comment: No, there is not. Why can't you just save the file?

Comment: @DanWilson I could, but I was hoping there was a way to do it without having to create temp files - the screenshots are saved after the screenshot is confirmed, but I wanted to avoid having unnecessary images being saved (e.g., the screenshot is previewed and deemed insufficient so another is taken).

Comment: You would have to create your own viewer to do that. Can you scale the image in the PictureBox?

Comment: You say:  "if the image being previewed was large, the screenshot is kind of useless".  Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072215/sending-picturebox-contents-to-mspaint

Answer (score 0):

I find it would be easier if you just saved it and opened it with a software. I tried to find many different ways to not save the file, but there aren't any unfortunately, so I have to save it and open with a tool like this: http://www.paintshoppro.com/en/pages/bmp-file/